# Gravando dados de uma SESSION no BD

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, session

Gostaria de adicionar no campo *cadastradopor* o *nome_funcionario* logado para banco de dados.

```
<?php 
    require_once("../../../session.php");
    require_once("../../../class.user.php");
    $auth_user = new USER();
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
    $stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM cad_funcionarios WHERE id_funcionario=:id_funcionario");
    $stmt->execute(array(":id_funcionario"=>$user_id));
    $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $stmt = $auth_user->runQuery('INSERT INTO cadastro_clientes (numerocontrato, id_cpf_cnpj, nome_completo, adesao, cpfoucnpj, cpfoucnpjnumero, data_nascimento, email, cep, rua, numero, bairro, cidade, estado, id_vendedor, id_forma_pagamento, id_forma, id_sexo, data_vencimento, id_revenda, id_plano, id_acomodacao, telefone, celular, total, cadastradopor, data_hora_cadastro, nomedependente, cpfdependente, datanascimentodependente, planodependente, acomodacaodependente, grauparentescodependente, valordependente) VALUES (:numerocontrato, :id_cpf_cnpj, :nome_completo, :adesao, :cpfoucnpj, :cpfoucnpjnumero, :data_nascimento, :email, :cep, :rua, :numero, :bairro, :cidade, :estado, :id_vendedor, :id_forma_pagamento, :id_forma, :id_sexo, :data_vencimento, :id_revenda, :id_plano, :id_acomodacao, :telefone, :celular, :total, :cadastradopor, NOW(), :nomedependente, :cpfdependente, :datanascimentodependente, :planodependente, :acomodacaodependente, :grauparentescodependente, :valordependente)');

    foreach ($_POST['usuarios'] as $usuario) {
        $usuario['numerocontrato']= $_POST['numerocontrato'];
        $usuario['id_cpf_cnpj']= $_POST['id_cpf_cnpj'];
        $usuario['nome_completo']= $_POST['nome_completo'];
        $usuario['adesao']= $_POST['adesao'];
        $usuario['cpfoucnpj']= $_POST['cpfoucnpj'];
        $usuario['cpfoucnpjnumero'] = $_POST['cpfoucnpjnumero'];
        $usuario['data_nascimento'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['data_nascimento']));
        $usuario['email'] = $_POST['email'];
        $usuario['cep'] = $_POST['cep'];
        $usuario['rua'] = $_POST['rua'];
        $usuario['numero'] = $_POST['numero'];
        $usuario['bairro'] = $_POST['bairro'];
        $usuario['cidade'] = $_POST['cidade'];
        $usuario['estado'] = $_POST['estado'];
        $usuario['id_vendedor'] = $_POST['id_vendedor'];
        $usuario['id_forma_pagamento'] = $_POST['id_forma_pagamento'];
        $usuario['id_forma'] = $_POST['id_forma'];
        $usuario['id_sexo'] = $_POST['id_sexo'];
        $usuario['data_vencimento'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['data_vencimento']));
        $usuario['id_revenda'] = $_POST['id_revenda'];
        $usuario['id_plano'] = $_POST['id_plano'];
        $usuario['id_acomodacao'] = $_POST['id_acomodacao'];
        $usuario['telefone'] = $_POST['telefone'];
        $usuario['celular'] = $_POST['celular'];
        $usuario['total']= $_POST['total'];
        $stmt->execute($usuario); 
} 
echo 'Cadastro realizado com sucesso<br><br>';

echo "<h1>" . $userRow['nome_funcionario'] .  "</h1>";

//header('refresh:6;cad_usuarios.php');
?>
```

Comment: Qual a lógica desse `foreach` ? oO ... Poderia editar a pergunta? Está muito vaga, nem tem variável de sessão aí, como vai salvar no banco se não há essas variáveis?

Comment: Esse foreach serve para gravar os dados do responsével + os dependentes @lvcs eu nao to sabendo fazer e nem como colocar a sessao

Comment: "id de um usuário logado no banco de dados" - De que usuário você está falando? Do `root`? Se não for, de que maneira esses usuários fazem `logon`?

Comment: @MauroSantos me parece que o `foreach` sempre pega os mesmo dados, por isso não entendi, acho que seja o caso de você editar a pergunta colocando o que quer fazer, mas na pergunta só há código, explique o que está querendo fazer, com detalhes.

Comment: Você aceitou uma resposta que nada tem a ver com o que foi perguntado. **Edite sua pergunta**.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você pretende colocar o valor `$userRow['nome_funcionario']` no campo `cadastradopor`, basta colocar adicionar uma linha no seu `foreach` antes do `$stmt->execute($usuario);`:

```
$usuario['cadastradopor'] = $userRow['nome_funcionario']
```

Answer (score 0):

A conexão PDO está funcionando direito?

Se sim, experimenta fazer dessa forma:

```
<?php 
    require_once("conexao.php");
    $pdo = Database::conexao();

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO cadastro_clientes (numerocontrato, id_cpf_cnpj, nome_completo, adesao, cpfoucnpj, cpfoucnpjnumero, data_nascimento, email, cep, rua, numero, bairro, cidade, estado, id_vendedor, id_forma_pagamento, id_forma, id_sexo, data_vencimento, id_revenda, id_plano, id_acomodacao, telefone, celular, total, data_hora_cadastro, nomedependente, cpfdependente, datanascimentodependente, planodependente, acomodacaodependente, grauparentescodependente, valordependente) VALUES (:numerocontrato, :id_cpf_cnpj, :nome_completo, :adesao, :cpfoucnpj, :cpfoucnpjnumero, :data_nascimento, :email, :cep, :rua, :numero, :bairro, :cidade, :estado, :id_vendedor, :id_forma_pagamento, :id_forma, :id_sexo, :data_vencimento, :id_revenda, :id_plano, :id_acomodacao, :telefone, :celular, :total, NOW(), :nomedependente, :cpfdependente, :datanascimentodependente, :planodependente, :acomodacaodependente, :grauparentescodependente, :valordependente)');

    foreach ($_POST['usuarios'] as $usuario) {
        $stmt->bindParam(1,$usuario['numerocontrato']);
        $stmt->bindParam(2,$usuario['id_cpf_cnpj']);
        $stmt->bindParam(3,$usuario['nome_completo']);
        /*Completa as outras*/
} 

$stmt->execute(); 

echo 'Cadastro realizado com sucesso<br><br>';
//header('refresh:6;cad_usuarios.php');
?>
```

Comment: Só por curiosidade, o que essa resposta tem a ver com `session`?

Comment: Como NÃO há nada com session na pergunta dele a não ser o título, então apenas achei que poderia melhora.

Comment: Melhorei o código, agora ta pegando session @CarlosRocha, so não to sabendo fazer para adicionar.

Comment: Melhora, mas não responde, @carlos-rocha.

Comment: @CarlosRocha nesse caso, quando você ver que a pergunta está um pouco confusa, sugiro não responder. Provavelmente, se ela não for fechada, será editada. E se ela for editada, sua resposta ficará invalida. Daí você vai ter que editar, porque alguém vai querer negativar se ela não for válida.

Comment: Quer dizer que o insert não está funcionando? É isso?

Comment: Whallace, entendi! Vou tomar precaução da próxima vez. Ou devo excluir a resposta?

Comment: @MauroSantos, se você fizer print_r($_POST['usuarios']), o que sai no navegador?